# Error: Property 'x' does not exist on type '[number, number]'

Tags: d3.js, path

I am running into a problem creating a line graph.

First, my `return d.x` and `return d.y` does not work. I get the error:

> `Property 'x' does not exist on type '[number, number]' .`

Interface code:

```
export interface TestItem { "x": number, "y": number }
```

Sample Data:

```
let lineData = [{
    "x": 1,
    "y": 5
}, {
    "x": 20,
    "y": 20
}, {
    "x": 40,
    "y": 10
}, {
    "x": 60,
    "y": 40
}, {
    "x": 80,
    "y": 5
}, {
    "x": 100,
    "y": 60
}];
```

Line command:

```
let svgLine = d3.svg.line().x(function(d) {
  return d.x;
})
.y(function(d) {
  return d.y;
})
.interpolate("linear");
```

Second Issue: my append path command also has a problem:

The `svgLine(lineData)` as the following error:

> Argument of type '{ "x": number; "y": number; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[number, number][]'.
>       Type '{ "x": number; "y": number; }' is not assignable to type '[number, number]'.
>           Property '0' is missing in type '{ "x": number; "y": number; }'.

I have referenced multiple examples and they all have the same code. So I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Using your lineData array and your svgLine function, I don't get any errors: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5svs6kLg/)

Comment: Ya. I don't get it either ????????????? Thanks for checking.

Comment: If you are using Typescript, did you try to specify the type of items used for you line? Such as `d3.line<TestItem>()` (in d3.v4) or `d3.svg.line<TestItem>()` (in d3.v3)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3/v3/index.d.ts#L2213-L2215) for D3 v3 one notices that a `d3.svg.line()` generator comes in two flavors: (1) either using the default type `[number, number]` or (2) by specifying your own type:

```
namespace svg {
    export function line(): Line<[number, number]>;   // (1)
    export function line<T>(): Line<T>;               // (2)
```

Since you have not provided any type argument when creating the line generator in your statement

```
let svgLine = d3.svg.line()
```

the TypeScript compiler will use the above case (1) assuming your data be in a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) containing two numbers.

This clearly conflicts with your data structure in `lineData` which is an array of objects, not an array of well-defined tuples. Hence, the compiler errors you witnessed.

As can be seen from the declarations the workaround for this is simple. You can easily pass in your interface `TestItem` to initialize the line generator to the appropriate type:

```
let svgLine = d3.svg.line()<TestItem>
  .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
  .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
  .interpolate("linear");
```